# Uploading files with Livewire width file .tiff delete an "f"

Tags: file, upload, tiff, laravel-livewire, temporary

For some reason when I upload files of type .tiff, it cuts an "f" changing the file to foo.tif, this causes problems with both the preview:

```
@foreach ($files as $file)
       Photo preview:
         <img src="{{ $file->temporaryUrl() }}" class = "w-32">
@endforeach`
```

and then, since I need to convert the files to webp, obviously the file is not recognized as an image and the conversion fails.

I have tried this both locally and on the server. I think it's a Livewire bug.
Has anyone encountered this problem?
I did a lot of searches but couldn't find anything.